# Find the volume of $D⊂\mathbb R^3$ where $D=\{(x,y,z):(x^2+ y^2 + z^2 )^2 ≤ 4xyz, x≥0, y≥0\}$.

Tags: integration, geometry, boundary-value-problem

I have a problem where I am to find the volume of $D⊂\mathbb R^3$ where
$$D=\{(x,y,z):(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 )^2  ≤ 4xyz, x≥0, y≥0\}.$$
I do not know how to tackle such problem with these inequalities and would like som help on how to get started

Comment: You can star with ${\rm Vol}(D)=\iiint_{D}1dV$.